# android:how to Reload the ArrayAdapater Class in Check/uncheck event of ListView's Chekbox?

Tags: android, android-emulator

How to Reload the ArrayAdapater Class in Check/uncheck event of ListView's Chekbox? 
the Event is define in ArrayAdapter Class? notifieddatachage() is not worked..

I want to reload the ArrayAdpater class for reload the View again for user when clicked the Chekbox that time but its not workd so please help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on check/Uncheck event call refresh();

```
public void refresh()
        {
            mCursor=db_conn.onQueryGetCursor("tab_book",mItems,null, null, null, null, null);
            mCursor.requery();
            notifyDataSetChanged();

       }
```

Comment: Thanks for Help..your Refresh() Method logic is worked on my appliation

Comment: ohhh thanx, best of luck for further Obstacle