# notifyDataSetChanged not working?

Tags: android, spinner

```
ArrayList valforspinner=new ArrayList();

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=null;

    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner01);
     adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Printers);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);


new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {         
        valforspinner= GetList.List(myPrefs.getString("IP", ""));
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }}).start();
```

When the result comes in the arraylist i.e the values,still the spinner remains empty??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`notifyDataSetChanged()` needs to be called from a UI thread. Try to use [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Answer (score -1):

may this will be helpful
[android:how to Reload the ArrayAdapater Class in Check/uncheck event of ListView's Chekbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799913/androidhow-to-reload-the-arrayadapater-class-in-check-uncheck-event-of-listview/5799994#5799994)