# Remove item from the listview in Android

Tags: android, listview

I want to delete the item from the listview

my code is for listview

```
this.lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(FindFilesByType.this, android.R.layout.test_list_item,Ringtones));
//          setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(FindFilesByType.this, R.layout.main,
//                  Ringtones));
//          
            this.lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> aView, View v,
                        int position, long id) {
                    currentPosition = position;
                    playRingtone(DIRECTORY+Ringtones.get(position));
                    Toast.makeText(FindFilesByType.this, "postion  "+DIRECTORY+Ringtones.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                GlobalVariable.SetstrEmail(DIRECTORY+Ringtones.get(position));
                GlobalVariable.SetcurrentPosition(position);
                }
            });
```

now how can i delete selected item from it?

Answer (score 1):

may this help
[android:how to Reload the ArrayAdapater Class in Check/uncheck event of ListView's Chekbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799913/androidhow-to-reload-the-arrayadapater-class-in-check-uncheck-event-of-listview/5799994#5799994)

Answer (score 1):

I have used like this in my code, it can delete multiple items from the list

```
ListView lv_ArchivePartylist;

ArrayList<Parties> select_archived_party;

lv_ArchivePartylist = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.archive_ListView01);
            lv_ArchivePartylist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
                {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(view.findViewById(R.id.img_chkbox_archive).getVisibility()==TextView.GONE)
                    {
                        view.findViewById(R.id.img_chkbox_archive).setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
                        Toast.makeText(ctx_archive, "Name="+archived_parties.get(position).getPartyTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    select_archived_party.add(archived_parties.get(position));
    }
    }

});
```

Then I've declared one button of "Delete" and on it's On ClickListener method, it calls the code from the database(In your case it may be Arraylist or array) to delete the items selected in Arraylist "select_archived_party".
Hope it helps :-)

Comment: Hi Jaydeep, I reformatted the code, rollback if you don't like it.

Comment: @ MByD -->Thank You,now that will be easier for all to read..Thanks for your help