# Delete selected item from List view

Tags: android, listview

I have developed a code in which i have populated list view dynamically.

now i want to delete the selected item from list view on button click(on pressing delete button)

I have searched out this in this site but didn't got any exact solution so i am posting this question

please help me how to do this :

code on delete buttons onClickListener is as shown below :

```
DeleteButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (idx >= 0) {
                Log.v("Item index deleted", idx + "");
                idx = OdrLst.getCheckedItemPosition();
                String delete = (String) ((OdrLst.getAdapter())
                        .getItem(idx));
                // Long deteteId = OdrLst.getAdapter().getItemId(idx);
                Log.d("Item deleted", delete);
                Log.d("adapter count before", adapter.getCount() + "");
                Log.d("lv count before", OdrLst.getCount() + "");
                // Log.d("listitems count before", listItems.+"");
                adapter.remove(delete);
                //listItems.remove(idx);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                OdrLst.setAdapter(adapter);
                // OdrLst.removeViewAt(idx);
                // adapter.clear();
                Log.d("adapter count after", adapter.getCount() + "");
                Log.d("lv count after", OdrLst.getCount() + "");
                //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                // Log.v("adapter count after 1", adapter.getCount()+"");
            }
            // cleared = false; // <--- nope, we did not clear the value yet
            // delItem();
        }
    });
```

This code shows exact position and item to be deleted but the item not gets removed from the listview...

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250770/how-to-refresh-android-listview)

Comment: no its not the duplicate question as on this link i want to delete items from listview on click of delete button

Comment: hello everybody i have edited the code of delete button as shown above now by this code all the items in the listview . can anybody please edit my code to delete only the selected item ?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this after removing the item.

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: do i need to setOnItemClickListener on my listview inside delete buttons OnClick event ???

Comment: Finally i am able to delete the selected item from listview . The code that worked for me is : public void onClick(View v) {
    if (idx != 0) {
     String delete = (String) ((OdrLst.getAdapter()).getItem(idx));
     //Log.d("Item deleted", delete);
     adapter.remove(delete);
     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     OdrLst.setAdapter(adapter);
     //Log.d("adapter count after", adapter.getCount() + "");
     //Log.d("lv count after", OdrLst.getCount() + "");
    }
   }

Comment: isn't that the same thing? :S It was clearly something to do with your adapter code. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can make a customized Listview containing check boxes or imageview and then use Arraylist to get the items which were clicked in the list.
refer these link:
[Remove item from the listview in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803043/remove-item-from-the-listview-in-android/5839303#5839303)